# BPXLUUIDHandler Unhandled Keychain Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, uuid

I'm using [BPXLUUIDHandler](https://github.com/blackpixel/BPXLUUIDHandler) library in my application for a while. After iOS9 I start to take some strange error in [crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com) error logs. I try to catch error in my devices but I wasn't luck until today! Some how today it shows itself and crash the application.

Here is only error log that I have :

```
BPXLUUIDHandler Unhandled Keychain Error 4294933278
```

means this method was unsuccessful :

```
[BPXLUUIDHandler UUID]
```

I check the library's code and find the error log's line, but hard to say why.

```
static NSString *_uuid = nil;
+ (NSString *)UUID
{
    if (_uuid != nil)
        return _uuid;

    // Build a query
    CFMutableDictionaryRef query = CreateKeychainQueryDictionary();

    // See if the attribute exists
    CFTypeRef attributeResult = NULL;
    OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching(query, (CFTypeRef *)&attributeResult);
    if (attributeResult != NULL)
        CFRelease(attributeResult);

    if (status != noErr) 
    {
        CFRelease(query);
        if (status == errSecItemNotFound) // If there's no entry, store one
        {
            return [[self class] storeUUID:NO];
        }
        else // Any other error, log it and return nil
        {
            NSLog(@"BPXLUUIDHandler Unhandled Keychain Error %ld", status);
            return nil;
        }
    }
```

Anyone fix this issue before, or knows how to?